# Magento2 Checkout Page web matrix Shipping Method by default selected

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, frontend, shipping-methods

In Magento 2 checkout page when ship here button click than shipping method radio button by default selected showing but in my site it's not working.
So if anyone knows how to fix this, please reply me.

I have attached below screenshots for looks better idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select Matrix shipping to be defualt.

To achieve this, we need to override a javascript from Magento_Checkout module.

Find solution on this:
[How to set default shipping method in case of multiple shipping methods in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163419/how-to-set-default-shipping-method-in-case-of-multiple-shipping-methods-in-magen)

Comment: I am using module  for default shiping seelcted but in order box not showing shipping price. when i click in selected radio shipping method than  change  it

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/313671/57334 anyone help me thanks