# Magento 2: display shipping option initially

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I have only one shipping method in my store (DHL). It comes with a lot of additional options. But those only show once I click on the method's radio button.

This is where the magic somehow happens:

```
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shippingAdditional') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

How can I get magento to display those options initially without the need of a click on the radion button?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea you may try custom javascript i.e trigger onclick function at pageload to show all options.

```
$(function() {
   $( "#radioButtonId" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to make some code changes

Have you seen anything like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163919/70343