# Magento2 - auto select shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

`Magento2.2.7`.

Want to auto select first shipping method while multiple shipping there or auto select while single method there on checkout page.

Already try [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163919/14537) but not working for me.

Comment: please check https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-preselect-shipping-payment-extension.html. it is free and I used it as well!

Comment: @Pawan Thank you. But Want to auto select first shipping method while multiple shipping there

Comment: there is option to select first one, please see screen shot of module.

Comment: @Shorabh,I am sure you were using any third party module if solution is not working as per your link.Please check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 6):

You need to override core file in your theme

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js

**Override file in your theme** : sendorname/theme/Magento_Chekout/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js

and check line number 151 code

```
   if (ratesData.length === 1) {
        //set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
        selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);

        return;
    }
```

You can see here this code check that if only one shipping method thaen automatic got selected.So you need to changed the conditon here that if more than one shipping method then first should be selected with below code

```
  if (ratesData.length >= 1) {
            //set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
            selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);

            return;
        }
```

Now Cache clear and go to checkout page ,you will see first shipping method will automatic got selected.

**Note:** If you are using any third party one step checkout module then you need to search same file to override in your theme.

Comment: Is this also the file to edit when you want this behaviour on the CART page (NOT Checkout page)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ready made module, It is **free** and from BSS commerce.

> https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-preselect-shipping-payment-extension.html

**Note:** You can select shipping of your choice Or first one

I used above module in some of my project.

Answer (score 1):

create **{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js** file

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': true
            },
        }
    }
}
```

then create **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js** file

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method'
],function (_, wrapper, checkoutData, selectShippingMethodAction) {
    'use strict';

    return function (checkoutDataResolver) {

        var resolveShippingRates = wrapper.wrap(
            checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingRates,
            function (originalResolveShippingRates, ratesData) {

                // if selected shipping method is null then set default shipping method using the ratesData and selectShippingMethodAction in case of multiple shipping method 
                if (!checkoutData.getSelectedShippingRate() && ratesData.length > 1) {
                    selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);
                }
                
                return originalResolveShippingRates(ratesData);
            }
        );

        return _.extend(checkoutDataResolver, {
            resolveShippingRates: resolveShippingRates
        });
    };
});
```

- Run a setup upgrade : php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- Do a static
  deploy : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Alternatively, you can download the module here which allows you to select a default shipping and payment method : [Default Shipping & Payment](https://github.com/hungersoft/magento2-default-shipping-payment)