# Magento2: How to set default payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, credit-card

I want to set the default payment Credit Card option on the checkout page.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show default payment method as checked at checkout page in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159815/how-to-show-default-payment-method-as-checked-at-checkout-page-in-magento-2)

Comment: please check https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-preselect-shipping-payment-extension.html

Comment: This is working for me @Pawan

Comment: Welcome @MasudShaikh, above comment is in answer at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305574/magento2-auto-select-shipping-method/305579#305579

Answer (score 1):

The Magento built-in payment methods don't support the ability to select a default payment.

But, if you have custom payment method and if your custom js component extends `Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\default.js`, you can use `selectPaymentMethod` method to set your payment as the default one.

```
define(['Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'], function(Component) {
    initObservable: function () {
        this._super();
        this.selectPaymentMethod();
        ...
    }
});
```

If your payment js component has lazy initialization, you should call `selectPaymentMethod` on some `onReady` event.

Comment: Please let me know we need to create a new js file.